# VB script to only remove . after name

Tags: vbscript

I wish to remove . after name using VB script. For e.g. "kamal kaur." Also if the . is in between, it should be retained, e.g. kamal.kaur How it can be done?

Answer (score 0):

You can try like this code :

```
MyVar = "kamal.kaur."
MsgBox MyVar
MsgBox Remove_Last_Dot(MyVar)
'------------------------------------------
Function Remove_Last_Dot(s)
  If Right(s,1) = "." Then 
    Remove_Last_Dot = Left(s, Len(s) - 1) 
  Else 
    Remove_Last_Dot = s
  End If
End Function
'------------------------------------------
```